# ForEach loop code not working in promises while using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js

everyone! I am new to nodeJs. I've been working in a project recently that requires me to push into an array certain values. The code I wrote is not working, and I assume it has to do with promises.
This is my code:

```js
router.get('/dashboard/misTalleres', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  let misTalleres = req.user.talleres;
  let arrayTalleres = [];
  misTalleres.forEach((taller) => {
    Taller.findOne({_id: taller})
      .then((tallerFound) => {
        arrayTalleres.push(tallerFound);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  });

  console.log(arrayTalleres);
  // console.log(arrayTalleres);
  res.render('misTalleres', { name: req.user.name })

});
```

I need to push into arrayTalleres the return values from the Taller.findOne.

Thanks for any help in advanced!
Tom.

Comment: I assume that `Taller.findOne` is an async function. `console.log(arrayTalleres)` is most likely called before the async function is returned.

Comment: @DPac `then` is a promise method that is *guaranteed* to call its callback asynchronously

Comment: @Bergi The code above is calling `console.log(arrayTalleres)` outside `then`. At that time the array is probably still empty.

Comment: @DPac `s/probably/definitely`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (and avoid `forEach`):

```
let misTalleres = req.user.talleres;
Promise.all(misTalleres.map(taller => {
  return Taller.findOne({_id: taller});
})).then(arrayTalleres => {
  console.log(arrayTalleres);
  res.render('misTalleres', { name: req.user.name })
}, err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `Promise.all`.

**Steps:**

1. Create a list of promises
2. Pass that list into Promise.all
3. Wait for Promise.all to resolve

**Code:**

```
router.get('/dashboard/misTalleres', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const misTalleres = req.user.talleres;

  // list of promises
  const promise_array = misTalleres.map((taller) => Taller.findOne({ _id: taller }) );

  // execute all promises simultaneaously 
  Promise.all(promise_array).then(arrayTalleres => {
    console.log(arrayTalleres);
    res.render('misTalleres', { name: req.user.name })
  });

});
```

Comment: This was also helpful! Thanks for the explanation!